# Difference in Round function of Sybase ASE and Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rounding, sap-ase

The following query is run on **Sybase ASE**

```
SELECT ROUND(FixedRate,2) AS FixedRate FROM TableName WHERE ID=10000905;
```

result is

FixedRate

**0.28**

The following query is run on **Oracle 11g**

```
SELECT Round(FIXED_RATE,2) AS FixedRate FROM TableName WHERE ID=10000905;
```

result is

FIXEDRATE

**0.29**

The unrounded values in both db's is 0.285. Datatype of FixedRate in sybase is float and in Oracle is float(126).

Why is there a difference(0.28 in Sybase and 0.29 in Oracle) and how can I make it same in both the databases?

Comment: What is the full unrounded value in both databases? And what is the data type for each?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `float` in the first place. Use an **exact** numeric type like `number` in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, SYBASE does not use Base-10 encoding for FLOATS, so that .285 is being stored as something like .284999999999999999. This is why it is rounding down as opposed to Oracle's rounding up. Oracle's TRUNC(FIXED_RATE,2) and SYBASE's TRUNCATE(fixed_rate,2) would both return 0.28, but if you want correct rounding up then you will need to reconsider the data type that you are storing the numbers with because FLOAT has the potential for inherent inaccuracies in BOTH systems.